# After OS python upgrade, virtualenv python failing with "undefined symbol: _PyLong_AsInt¨ error on simple tasks

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I had a long-working virtualenv based on python-2.7.3. After accepting recommended platform OS (Ubuntu) updates which (among many other changes) brought python up to 2.7.6, the python inside the virtualenv has started erroring on essentially all non-trivial tasks, with stacks ending like:

```
ImportError: /home/myusername/ENVS/myvenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: _PyLong_AsInt
```

Even `pip freeze` is failing with such an error -- making it impossible to even get an accurate inventory of installed packages in the broken virtualenv (for potentially reinstalling into a fresh working virtualenv)!

Shouldn't the virtualenv be protected from such outside upgrades? Or at least within the 2.7.x series?

Answer (score 13):

You can simply do

```
cp /usr/bin/python2 /path/to/my-virtualenv/bin/python2
```

or

```
cp /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/my-virtualenv/bin/python3
```

Comment: Worked for me switching from 3.4.0 to 3.4.3 (Did also copy same file to env/bin/python and env/bin/python3.4)

Comment: I was able to track this issue back to this: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2931

Answer (score 2):

The virtualenv is referencing the external installation -- in this case, the `myvenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload` path is actually a softlink to `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload`, which has been updated. So maybe rolling back to 2.7.3 could work?

Tried downloading 2.7.3 source from python.org, and built/installed with the usual incantations (*even aware this is clobbering the system-preferred python, a risk I could take with a full-system VM snapshot*):

```
cd Python-2.7.3/
./configure 
make
sudo make install
```

Still no luck: same error, even though the softlink is now pointing to a 2.7.3-based resource. But how about copying the system /usr/bin/python-2.7 into the virtualenv? (I was reluctant to that with a different version, but at this point, why not?)

That resolved the problem. The virtualenv is now working, at least allowing some testing and extraction of "pip freeze" inventory. Of course outside stuff dependent on 2.7.6 might now be broken.

And, it *may* have been enough, and safe, to have just pulled the system 2.7.6 python executable into the virtualenv to replace its broken version. (Don't know -- other answers/resources imply problems upgrading a python inside a virtualenv unless reinstalling all packages afterwards, though they mainly address non-point revisions like 2.5 -> 2.6.)